# Windows Server 2012 - Event Viewer Filter XML custom query not working

Tags: events, xpath, windows-server-2012-r2, event-log, xpath-1.0

I am using the event log and task scheduler on windows server 2012 to run a script based on an event. This application does not write to the event log very nicely. Event IDs are only 0 or 1 with the Event Data being the only unique thing to query. I wonder if my problem has to do with the colons and/or spacing?

This is the XML data in the event log that I need to look for:

```
<EventData> 
<Data>in Tgo_iadminCommon.CommitTransaction: Error ending transaction... MSG is: General SQL error. ORA-03114: not connected to ORACLE</Data> 
</EventData>
```

This is my query, with cut and paste of the event data:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Application">
    <Select Path="Application">*[EventData[Data='in Tgo_iadminCommon.CommitTransaction: Error ending transaction... MSG is: General SQL error. ORA-03114: not connected to ORACLE']]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

No results. However, when this is my query, it works fine so I wonder if it has to do with spacing and/or colons?

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Application">
    <Select Path="Application">*[EventData[Data='in TWTHL7Service.ServiceStart, Error Calling Create Objects']]
</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

I thought of doing something like powershell, I'm not overly familiar, so I haven't gone that route yet. I know that the event log filter can't use wildcards or "contains" when performing a query. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else stumbles across this, I (happily) got around this with Powershell, which allows querying for text contained in the message.
If(Get-EventLog -After (get-Date).AddMinutes(-5) -LogName Application -Source '*WTHL7*' -Message '*not connected to ORACLE*')